# Issue with async, JS Promise not able to return a result, but works with console.log

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, promise

Currently it works when I use console.log(result) in my "exports.findOneProblem" while running "node jkl.js". I am able to see the result. However, when I use return instead of console.log(), all I get is a Promise {pending} in console. Please fill in the gaps .... learning how to work with promises, thanks.

```
 //asd.js

    exports.findOneProblem = function(problemId) {
          return RClient.authenticate(options).then(function (client) {
            const Problem = client.Problem;

            return Problem.findOne(problemId)
          }).then(function(result){
              return result
          });
        };
```

the second file: jkl.js

```
var okay = require('./asd');

var moneymoney = okay.findOneProblem(263)

console.log(moneymoney)


var honeyhoney = moneymoney.then(function(result){
  return result
})
console.log(honeyhoney)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you receive a Promise, that means you're going to get a value "later" i.e. after all of your synchronous code is done running. The way to access a value provided by a Promise is using the `.then` function.

```
moneymoney.then(function(result) {
  console.log(result);
  // Add your code for using the result of `okay.findOneProblem(263)` here
});
```